# meaning of "Be swim tested"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

A member of our rowing team has send me the following message, but I do not understand it. Could someone please explain it?

> just confirm with me that you are swim tested

Comment: Confirm that you have taken a test to show that you are able to swim to the standard required for entry to the rowing team. You would probably have been given a certificate or some kind of record.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a domain-specific turn of phrase that wouldn't mean anything to most native speakers without the relevant context.  And *with* that context, even a non-native speaker should be able to guess the meaning just as well the natives.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means have your swimming abilities been tested. of course, you could write the person who sent you the email and ask!

Comment: I'd go so far as to say there's almost certainly some official test of swimming ability to get on the rowing team that one must pass by getting in the water and performing a swimming test in front of some authorized official to prove one at least meets a high enough standard of swimming ability to not drown if and when suddenly overboard in deep water, as happens in rowing, without which one, for liability reasons, can't be on the rowing team. The question's asking for confirmation that test's been passed. If no, that's the next step. If yes, the respondent will later be asked to submit proof.